# I downgrade to 2.6.10 when I try to upgrade mongodb from 3.2 to 3.4

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, upgrade

I run in console:

```
mongod --version
db version v3.2.8
```

I want to upgrade its version to 3.4.

I visited https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community and downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 linux 64bit-64 (actually my Linux version is 15.10 but I couldn't find it in the download version list). After the download, I unziped downloaded file.

How should I continue?

---

edit : I continue as;

I first delete all as; 
`sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`

Then run `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb`

After the installation I just realize that the version is now `db version v2.6.10` Why this happened? I manage to downgrade...

Comment: Goggle is your friend. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @Dummy To be honest, answer is not that obvious at first glance, because theoretically there could be some simple command for Mongo update, without necessity of downloading new version from page.

Comment: I edited my question. Now it's pretty clear that I downgrade it :)

Comment: Your process you outlined would have downgraded it. 15.10 is unsupported anyway. Best thing to do here is upgrade the OS to supported 16.04 with a newer Mongo.

Comment: If you are worried about losing everything, just copy your data directory and your config file, then, reinstall, then move those back into where you copied from. Easy